# From Windows to Ubuntu .. external disc folder invisible

Tags: external-hdd

I have an external disc formated in Ubuntu.

```
1.0 TB — 529 GB free (47.1% full)
/dev/sdb1
47B9-1675
Basic Data
FAT (32-bit version) — Mounted at /media/username/johnySs
```

I gave the disc to a friend and they connected it to a Windows desktop it had some movies in one folder but, after when I conected the external disc to Ubuntu the folder didn't show up, however I can see the folder in the terminal.

What can I do?

```
/dev/sdb1       932G  439G  493G  48% /media/newgeneration/johnySs
newgeneration@newgeneration:~$ cd /media/newgeneration/johnySs
newgeneration@newgeneration:/media/newgeneration/johnySs$ ls
1.pdf  2.pdf  GPS  Movies  songs
newgeneration@newgeneration:/media/newgeneration/johnySs$ ls -lha
total 2.4M
drwxr-xr-x    6 newgeneration newgeneration  32K Jan  1  1970  .
drwxr-x---+   3 root          root          4.0K Oct 24 21:42  ..
-rw-r--r--    1 newgeneration newgeneration 1.6M Jan 19  2018  1.pdf
-rw-r--r--    1 newgeneration newgeneration 542K Jan 11  2018  2.pdf
 drwxr-xr-x    2 newgeneration newgeneration  32K Oct  6 06:28  GPS
 drwxr-xr-x   16 newgeneration newgeneration  32K Oct  6 06:39  Movies
 drwxr-xr-x   14 newgeneration newgeneration  32K Oct  6 06:46  songs
drwxr-xr-x  211 newgeneration newgeneration  64K Oct 23 14:49 '...tis eho dei'
 newgeneration@newgeneration:/media/newgeneration/johnySs$
```

The folder name is 'tis eho dei'.

```
drwxr-xr-x  211 newgeneration newgeneration  64K Oct 23 14:49 '...tis eho dei'
newgeneration@newgeneration:/media/newgeneration/johnySs$ cd /media/newgeneration/johnySs/'...tis eho dei'
newgeneration@newgeneration:/media/newgeneration/johnySs/...tis eho dei$
```

Comment: You don't really need to add **Solved** in question title since this is Q&A site not a forum. If an answer helped you, you can simply mark that answer as accepted by click on tick/check mark under the answer. But if you solved your problem using solution other than listed in answer section, you can post that also as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because the first character of your foldername is '.', it is hidden in nautilus.

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files.

Comment: ty i will try this

Comment: YOU are the best .. SOLVED